# firebase .indexOn warning with autoId

Tags: swift, indexing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase to store some data. When I use queryOrderedByChild("count"), I get the following warning

Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "count" at /comments/-KM449ubmviUkGNIj2fq to your security rules for better performance

My firebase structure looks like this

```
  "comments" : {
"-KM449ubmviUkGNIj2fq" : {
  "-KM44Ax8MdcBBPT_BQiO" : {
    "count" : 3,
    "comment" : "a",
    "commentOwner" : "hakV4smGyveurPhFN7g9rad4xsP2",
    "date" : "1467890319.38933"
  },
  "-KM45-Eb6yvXSAfhBrLX" : {
    "count" : 2,
    "comment" : "b",
    "commentOwner" : "hakV4smGyveurPhFN7g9rad4xsP2",
    "date" : "1467890533.56065"
  },
  "-KM488JCKddZhbev466U" : {
    "count" : 4,
    "comment" : "c",
    "commentOwner" : "hakV4smGyveurPhFN7g9rad4xsP2",
    "date" : "1467891357.06534"
  },
  "-KM48SXJ83L7-mpE5nma" : {
    "count" : 0,
    "comment" : "d",
    "commentOwner" : "hakV4smGyveurPhFN7g9rad4xsP2",
    "date" : "1467891439.88917"
  },
  "-KM4AN_rj-ycRZYESnh_" : {
    "count" : 0,
    "comment" : "e",
    "commentOwner" : "hakV4smGyveurPhFN7g9rad4xsP2",
    "date" : "1467891944.01086"
  },
```

Basically, I want to generate a list of firebase snapshots with the highest number of counts (similar to number of likes).

Since my post and comments have their unique Ids generated from firebase, I am not sure what I should do in terms of indexing to eliminate the warning.

I have tried the following security rule and it does not work

```
  "rules": {
".read": "auth != true",
".write": "auth != true",
"comments" : {
  ".indexOn" : ["count"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are trying to query the comments for a specific post.

In that case you need to tell the database to index the comments for each post. The syntax for that is:

```
"rules": {
  ".read": "auth != true",
  ".write": "auth != true",
  "comments" : {
    "$commentId": {
      ".indexOn" : ["count"]
    }
  }
}
```

With this you can order the comments for a specific post by the value of their `count` property.

Comment: Thanks so much Frank. I stumbled across your name from other post and was hoping you would have the time to look at it which you did! Much appreciated. I'd like to read more about the $ symbol and how the syntax works. What would you recommend? Thanks

Comment: The $ just means that whatever rules you have under there apply to *each* child node. Within that section you can then use `$commentId` to refer to the matched node. To learn all about security rules, I highly recommend [the key to Firebase security](https://youtu.be/PUBnlbjZFAI) (video) from I/O